# Docker image build successfully but after docker run : Couldn't find the node_modules state file - running an install might help (findPackageLocation)

Tags: reactjs, docker, next.js, yarnpkg

I have a Next JS project which uses yarn 3.5.1 by default (it was a template) I can build the project via docker build successfully without any error. here is my docker file for this project:

```
# Stage 1: Build
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY .yarn ./.yarn
COPY .yarnrc.yml ./
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install --immutable

COPY . .

RUN yarn build

# Stage 2: Run
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/.yarn ./.yarn
COPY --from=builder /app/.yarnrc.yml ./
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/yarn.lock ./yarn.lock

ENV NODE_ENV=production

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

but when I want to run this image container I get this error message:

```
$ sudo docker run --restart=always -p 8080:80 next1
Usage Error: Couldn't find the node_modules state file - running an install might help (findPackageLocation)

$ yarn run [--inspect] [--inspect-brk] [-T,--top-level] [-B,--binaries-only] <scriptName> ...
```

I found a similar question in SO based on that I tried to use a different node version but issue not resolved. any tips or idea would be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you haven't copied node_modules from build step. Add this like to your code

```
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
```

Comment: could you please tell me where exactly should I put this?

Comment: You can put it after `COPY --from=builder /app/yarn.lock ./yarn.lock`